# Why a volume comparison is always returning false in a while loop?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I need to know what is the first bar (from the right) which the volume is higher than the previous one. Thing is that _found always is false whatever volume value is.

```
_count = 1
_found = false
while not _found and _count < 10
    _found := volume[_count] > volume[_count+1]
    _count := _count + 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be working.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay = true)
_count = 1
_found = false
while not _found and _count < 10
    if volume[_count] > volume[_count+1]
        _found := true
    else
        _count := _count + 1

if barstate.islast
    label.new(bar_index, high, str.tostring(_found) + '\n' + str.tostring(_count), color= color.lime)
```

3 bars back was the first day with volume > previous day excluding the current day
[image: true]